# How to get reference to the current router from ViewModel

Tags: aurelia

In my viewmodel class, how do I get a reference to the current Router?

What I really want to do is  get the current ModuleId.

In Durandal, there was system.getModuleId, but there is no system in Durandal, so I figure the router is going to have that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (not sure, the optimal one) to access current `moduleId` is in `activate` hook of your class:

```
activate(params, routeConfig) {
    console.log(routeConfig.moduleId);
}
```

Comment: is `activate` on all classes? if so, could you possibly decorate it? (this might be a different question altogether

Comment: yes, there is `activate` hook available for every viewmodel class. not sure about decoration it. it is also possible to inject router into viewmodel and check its `currentInstrustion.config.modelId`, but it's not nice.

Comment: this will only return config for current route, not router. @Greg Gum answer is the correct one.

Comment: `activate` is not available in every view model. only on modules that are loaded via the router or by `compose`. "regular` components don't have `activate`

Answer (score 3):

The way to get a reference to the current router:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {router} from 'aurelia-router'

@inject(router)
constructor(router)
{
    this.router = router; //Do something with router.
}
```

Note: Do not inject "AppRouter"  It's a different router.  If you add a route to AppRouter, it will not work.  It will work if you import Router.

Comment: I think you need to import {Router} from 'aurelia-router' (uppercase) and @inject(Router) (also uppercase). See https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/how-to-use-navigatetoroute/2581/6